# How to marshal XML from a map[string]interface{}?

Tags: go

I'm building an API to handle XML data in POST, and return it in the response. The function that should handle this marshaling is receiving variable data as type `map[string]interface{}` which looks like this (if you log it to the console):

```
map[lala:success blabla:0xc42011e700 status:true]
```

Replicating steps that worked for JSON marshaling or trying to follow the documentation got me in a dead end. This is the code I have so far:

```
type Map map[string]interface{}

type xmlMapEntry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Value   string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (m Map) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {

    for k, v := range m {
        e.Encode(xmlMapEntry{XMLName: xml.Name{Local: k}, Value: v})
    }

    return e.EncodeToken(start.End())
}
```

I got to a dead end when the e.Encode line returned: `cannot use v (type interface {}) as type string in field value: need type assertion`

Comment: "got me in a dead end" can you be more specific?

Comment: Modified origianal

Answer (score 1):

Solved. answer:
first, my struct VALUE was of type `string` instead of `interaface`, and second- to see the data parsing I had to actually marshal it.. using:
 `x, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(Map(data), "", "  ")`